# 'HTTP status code must be an integer' error in Django view

Tags: python, django

i have small scraping view in my Django website, but i get an error 'HTTP status code must be an integer' in line:

```
return HttpResponse(request, 'scrapingscore.html', {'original_link':original_link})
```

```
    def scraping(request):
        rootlink = 'https://www.transfermarkt.pl'
        link = 'https://www.transfermarkt.pl/schnellsuche/ergebnis/schnellsuche?query='
        if request.method == 'POST':
            data = request.POST.get("textfield")
            if data == '':
                empty = 'Data is empty'
                return HttpResponse(request, 'scrapingscore.html', {'empty':empty})
            else:
                data = data.replace(" ", "+")
                search = link + data + '&x=0&y=0'
                req = Request(
                        search,
                        data=None,
                        headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
                        }
                    )

                req = urlopen(req).read()
                soup = BeautifulSoup(
                                    req,
                                    features="lxml"
                                    )

                anchor = soup.find("a",{"class":"spielprofil_tooltip"})
                link = anchor.get("href")
                original_link = rootlink + link
                return HttpResponse(request, 'scrapingscore.html', {'original_link':original_link})
        return render(request, 'scraping.html')
```

I don't know why i get an error 'HTTP status code must be an integer'. I have one argument in dict in this line with error and i don't know how to repair it, i thought it will work but it is not.
When user input is blank, i also get this error in line

```
return HttpResponse(request, 'scrapingscore.html', {'empty':empty})
```

.
edit:
i added new lines:

```
template = loader.get_template('scrapingscore.html')
context = {
        'original_link': original_link,
    }
```

and in this line in error now i have:

```
return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

But now website is not redirecting to 'scrapingscore.html' - it stays on 'scraping.html' after submit input.

scraping.html

```
<form action="{% url 'scraping' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name="text" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Look at the arguments that `HttpResponse` expects. One of the first 3 is the status code, and you did not provide an integer for any of these

Comment: I don't know if i do it good or you mean something else, but i change a line to 'return HttpResponse(request, 'scrapingscore.html', {'original_link':original_link}, '401 Error', status=401)', now i get error '__init__() got multiple values for argument 'status''

Comment: Because one of the arguments is already for `status`, as my previous comment says. Do not guess. Read Django's documentation

Comment: Ok so i don't get it

Answer (score 0):

You are passing arguments wrong to [HttpResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects) class. Read How to use The HttpResponse class.

From what I see you Used the response class wrongly, it's more like you wanted to use [TemplateResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/template-response/) class:

```
return TemplateResponse(request, 'scrapingscore.html', {'original_link':original_link})
```

because HttpResponse class do not take a template(`'scrapingscore.html'`) and context(`{'original_link':original_link}`).

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your response :) I read documentation and i changed few lines, i added them at the bottom of my first post. Now i don't get error but i am not redirected with score to second webpage and nothing happens after submitting user input.

Comment: Hi, you get error because you are trying to use template with HttpResponse, however it does not work that way. you can use TemplateResponse. Replace HttpResponse with Template response. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thank you, i edited it and added line with TemplateResponse in both cases but it still doesn't redirect to 'scrapingscore.html', i have no idea why because code looks good.

Comment: maybe you have problem with the template? can django find it?

Comment: Yes, i have other views with this same path and there templates look and work good. It is strange because i think if it will be problem with finding template, there will be error and now there is no error, just webpage 'scraping.html' is refreshing. I added to first post how my 'scraping.html' file looks like, maybe there is problem with sending data but i don't think so :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209260/discussion-between-glyphack-and-noname).